# Need a very simple, clean and efficient WordPress starter

Tags: wordpress

I need to come up with a portfolio by tomorrow - I've done some web work in the past, but I never actually created a portfolio.

Could you suggest a clean and simple wordpress starter which I could make look good? I saw a number of them like Roots, but they all have too many complex elements and it would take me longer than one night to modify.

NOTE: I am not trying to make a portfolio theme - I am trying to make a theme to show off to an employer.

Comment: The default "Twenty Twelve" theme is straightforward. Try customizing that one, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using wordpress as the back end?  You can customize the front end to look like whatever you want, and then make calls to Wordpress posts and pages by boostrapping the Wordpress with themes.

Link to [Wordpress forum on this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>

</head>

<?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); require('[wordpress_installation]/wp-blog-header.php');?>

<body id="wrap">

<div class="posts">
        <?php query_posts('&cat=3'); //Specify a specific blog category if you want ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post">
            <div class="sub-title">
                <div style="padding:3px 0;"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                <div class="post_date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
            </div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I consider your need, this might be overkill.

Comment: Hm, so this is something that would in effect pull the posts from my wordpress install? Where would I place this PHP file?

Comment: Exactly.  So, you would point the `require()` function to wherever `wp-blog-header.php` was /wordpress/ you would add require as . `<?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); require('/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');?>`

Answer (score 0):

Check out any of the themes over at Devatic. Many are geared toward showing a collection / portfolio of work. All run around $30. But if you need it by tomorrow, worth the money.

Check out Essence or the other Creative themes

http://devatic.com/